# Converting jar file to exe

Tags: java, windows, jar, exe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I convert my Java program to an .exe file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file)

Is there any free tool to convert jar into exe ?? I searched but couldn't find effective software all are giving only trial versions!

Thanks!

Comment: An EXE does *not* work on *nix or OS X.  [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) **does.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although I never converted jar to exe, but while searching for the term, I found the following free utility:

JSmooth .exe wrapper
JSmooth is a Java Executable Wrapper. It creates native Windows launchers (standard .exe) for your java applications.
Download: http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/

source: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/02/convert-jar-to-exe-executable-jar-file-to-exe-converting.html

Comment: I have installed J Smooth. My computer has JDK 1.7 & JRE 1.7. but it says need java 1.4 or above to open & try to download. Why is that ??

Comment: Note that JWS supports Java 1.2+.  ;)

Comment: sorry, but I never tried this. May be you should try this utility:        http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/